# Tikz figure appears above subsection

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I have made a figure using TikZ and I want it to be inside a subsection after a few sentences, as shown in the following:

```
\newpage
    \section{Modeling}
    \subsection{Modeling Trajectory}
    This subsection's content...
    at this point I will....

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[anchor=north west] {x};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[anchor=south east] {y};
    \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- (5,2) node[anchor=north west] {$V_{T}$};
    \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- (1,4) node[anchor=south west] {$F_{Drag}$};
    \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- (3,1) node[anchor=north west] {g};
    \draw [dashed] (3,3) -- (6,3);
    \draw (4,3) arc (0:-28:1) node[] at (30:5.3)  {$\gamma_{T}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Ballistic target geometry}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

However, what I get is that the figure at the top of the page, then the section title and the the subsection title.

The result I needed is:

```
section title
subsection title
figure
```

I tried using `\floatbarrier` but it moves the whole figure to the center of other page.

Thank you.

Comment: Several things: (1) don't use the `center` env to center, both `center` and `figure` introduces vertical space. (2) use `\begin{figure}[htbp]` note the extra option. The default is `tbp` thus no 'here about', that extra `'h' is important. (3) Using the `H` is almost never a good solution as floats and end in the wrong over.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) or [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `H` option from `float` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,float}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\section{Modeling}
\subsection{Modeling Trajectory}
This subsection's content...
at this point I will....

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[anchor=north west] {x};
        \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[anchor=south east] {y};
        \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- (5,2) node[anchor=north west] {$V_{T}$};
        \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- (1,4) node[anchor=south west] {$F_{Drag}$};
        \draw[thick,->] (3,3) -- (3,1) node[anchor=north west] {g};
        \draw [dashed] (3,3) -- (6,3);
        \draw (4,3) arc (0:-28:1) node[] at (30:5.3)  {$\gamma_{T}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Ballistic target geometry}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: here!!]

Comment: This is not a good solution, the `H` option should not be used in general.

Answer (score 7):

The main issue here is the fact that the default float placement is `tbp` the `h` for **here if possible** has to be added manually. Thus use

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
```

Also both `figure` and `center` envs introduce vertical space, so the proper method of centering inside a figure is:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
 ....
\end{figure}
```

Also the `float` packages `H` option should the avoided as much as possible. People generally use it because they forget how to use the `[htbp]` options, and they forget that floats should go **nearby** not **HERE**